# HTML form max submittable length but still able to submit something larger via backend

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a HTML form in one to the inputs someone can add a phone number(min and max lenght of 10) but the customer (school) wants it that the standard value is "Nog niet ingevoerd". This is code that I have so far:

`<input type="text" min="0" name="Celphone_number" pattern=".{10,10}" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' placeholder="Telefoon nummer" value=<?php echo '"'. $data["Celphone_number"] . '"'?>/>`

Now my question is: is it possible to keep the min and max lenght of 10 but still able to send "Nog niet ingevoerd" to the next page.

Comment: It is very hard to understand what you are asking. Try to improve your question and add what you have tried so far.

Comment: Can you elaborate your question and show the code that how you are trying to set the possible length... Like if its a input box you can set max `<input type="text" name="usrname" maxlength="10">`

Comment: just updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. If you set a limit in a HTML form field, that's the length you can submit. You could of course resort to a Javascript work-around, but it seems rather pointless. Look into that only if this is an exercise in making funny little hacks to override your configuration.

If the user submits an empty value, simply check for an empty value in PHP, and then set it to *"Nog niet ingevoerd"*. There's no need to submit that phrase from the form. If you need to provide feedback on the user's input, then put it next to the input field, not into it.

Also do tell your professor that you should probably be working with (and storing in your database) a NULL for "no value provided" -- instead of a string in Dutch -- and getting that string from a separate language variable wherever required. Then you can: 1. Easily check if a phone number has been provided (instead of checking if the value is a valid phone number or your placeholder string), and 2. Translate your thingy into other languages. A good practice sort of thing, that.